# Need to change everytime the name in selenium

Tags: selenium, csv, selenium-webdriver

I need help because i'm trying to run a bot in a certain website. The thing is that i need to change the information every time (like name, phone...).

This is the selenium program:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import csv

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='../drivers/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://footpatrol.s3.amazonaws.com/content/site/2017/RaffleForm_Assets/FootPatrolRafflePage_FR-dunk-high-pro.html?fullTag=fr_adidas?shortTag=fr_adidas?prodcutName=Nike-Dunk-High?imgUrl=https://i8.amplience.net/i/jpl/nike-dunk-high-michigan-cz8149-700-release-date-2020-1-cea2e10c697d163cd225844dffd98596')



search = driver.find_element_by_id("fullName").send_keys("text")

search = driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("text")

search = driver.find_element_by_id("phoneNumber").send_keys("text")

search = driver.find_element_by_id("cityOfRes").send_keys("text")

search = driver.find_element_by_id("countryOfRes").send_keys("text")

search = driver.find_element_by_id("shoetype").send_keys("text")

search = driver.find_element_by_id("shoeSize").send_keys("text")

search = driver.find_element_by_id("termsAgreed").click()

search = driver.find_element_by_id("emailpermit").click()

search = driver.find_element_by_id("sms_optout").click()

search = driver.find_element_by_id("agepermit").click()

search = driver.find_element_by_id("submit").click()
```

I'm trying to make my program select everytime the element from my csv file, but i quite don't know how to meke this.
This is a draft, I'm not quite sure if it fits for this case.

```
with open('inaki - Feuil1.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    line_count = 0

    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(row[1])
            line_count += 1

        else:
            print(row[1])
            line_count = +1
```

I count to make a program for every function (name, phone number...)

Please help me do this, I'm really stuck since I'm a beginner.

Thanks, and sorry for being so bad at coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to convert the csv file to an array so you can repeat the task for all the values the array has like :

```
Import csv
   Values=[]#you can add more arrays depend on the information you want to save for each login 

with open('file.csv') as csvDataFile:
csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
for values in csvReader:
    data1.append(values[0])
    data2.append(values[1])

print(data1)
 print(data2)#here you can start the login process inside the for loop
```